# HTML content changes when testing in email client

Tags: html, css, email, testing

My content looks exactly how I want it when testing in browser, but after running it through email the Header is below the banner instead of on it - like how it is in Browser.

[image: How it looks in browser]

```
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #FBFBFB;">
        <div style="position: relative; text-align: center; color: white;">
            <img src="iphonebannerv3.png" width="600" height="" alt="Nielsen Header Banner" border="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; background: #FBFBFB; font-family: open sans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #555555; margin: auto;" class="g-img">
            <h1 style="margin: 0 0 0px 0; font-family: Open sans, sans-serif; font-size: 28px; text-align:center; line-height: 30px; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; position: absolute; top: 45%; left: 8%;">YOU'RE MISSING OUT<br> ON VOUCHERS</h1>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: With which e-mail clients are you testing your e-mails ? Outlook uses Word as rendering engine and therefor is not really supportive for css

Comment: I use ExactTarget but its now called Sales Force, Im new to email coding so I dont have much choice...

Comment: So you are trying to send e-mails into Sales Force and not out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Coding HTML email templates can be tricky. Instead of absolute positioning the H1, try setting **everything** fixed with tables. For example, In your TD I would start with a fresh table. For example:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FBFBFB">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"> 
 
  <table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x150" width="600" height="150" alt="Nielsen Header Banner" border="0" style="display: block; width: 600px; height: 150px;" class="g-img">
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background: #00aeef; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
       <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 28px; text-align: center; line-height: 30px; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;"> YOU'RE MISSING OUT<br> ON VOUCHERS</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr> 
      </tbody>
       </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table> 

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

You can use a Style tag in your CSS to keep your styles organised, and use a tool like https://inlinestyler.torchbox.com/ to move all your css inline before you finish the template. Also,

- Not everyone has Open Sans installed in their client,
- Define width and height on your images.
- An image does not require all the font CSS styles.
- Set everything with tables for the best cross-mailclient templates.

Good luck!